# /usr/sbin/apache2 not found

Tags: installation, apache2

I am trying to install and run apache2, but after `apt-get purge apache2;apt-get install apache2` (as root), I am still missing the file `/usr/sbin/apache2`

I am running Backtrack 5 RC 2, which is a Ubuntu devirate.

How can I fix that?

Comment: "I am running Backtrack 5 RC 2, which is a Ubuntu devirate." cool but this is going to get closed. According to the faq (http://askubuntu.com/faq)  non official derivates are not supported on AU (we are limited to these lubuntu, mythbuntu, xubuntu, medibuntu, ubuntu studio, kubuntu and edubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are purging, presumably you had it installed at some point and things went wrong.  The /usr/sbin/apache2 binary isn't provided by the apache2 package, but by one of its dependencies:

```
# dpkg -S /usr/sbin/apache2
apache2-mpm-prefork: /usr/sbin/apache2
```

If your binary is missing, but the package still installed, you can use the above command to figure out which package provides the binary and re-install.